# Ruby - Is there a way to get the instance of an eigenclass?

Tags: ruby, instance, eigenclass

I am looking for a way to get the instance of an eigenclass, since each eigenclass has only one instance.

I could look thru ObjectSpace be testing each eigenclass, but I guess it's expensive.

Curiously, I must get the eigenclass of each object to test the match, because `is_a?` does not suffice:

```
class A; end
class B < A; end

AA = class << A; self; end

p A.is_a? AA #=> true
p B.is_a? AA #=> true!!!!
```

I wish there was an `Class#instance` or `Class#instances` method to get the instance(s) of a class (or eigenclass).

The most direct way would be extract the instance from the eigenclass' `inspect`, but I'm wondering if I can rely on it:

```
p AA         #=> #<Class:A>
instance = Object.const_get(AA.inspect.match(/^#<Class:(\w+)>$/)[1])
p instance   #=> A

# (this works for class' eigenclass)
```

My use case is that I must get the class of a class method, but the `Method#owner` gives me the eigenclass, and `Method#receiver` gives me the current receiver:

```
# Continuing previous example
def A.f; end
mtd = B.method(:f)
p mtd.owner     #=> #<Class:A>
p mtd.receiver  #=> B
# I want to obtain A
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to find instances of any given class, you can use [`ObjectSpace`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/ObjectSpace.html):

```
class A; end
class B < A; end

ObjectSpace.each_object(A.singleton_class).to_a
# => [B, A]
```

Comment: What is method `singletonclass`?

Comment: @sawa, see the [`Object#singleton_class` method documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-singleton_class).

Comment: Great. I didn't know such method existed. Now, I can use it.

Comment: Good to know `singleton_class` (which doesn't work in 1.8.7 BTW, but I always can use `class << A; self; end` when needed). Your answer showed that the problem is far less complicated than I imagined. To obtain `A` I can use `ObjectSpace.each_object(A.singleton_class).to_a.last`. Thank you!

Comment: Not gonna to work on jruby, at least with disabled `ObjectSpace` by default

Comment: Given it is a singleton class, doesn't `A.singleton_class` return that single instance? Why need to scan object space?

Comment: @akostadinov Because subclasses of the class are also instances of its singleton class.

Comment: I actually confused the original question so my own question does not make much sense I see :)